# Please turn this into a loop

Tags: c++

I have been struggling in making this a loop. Any help would be appreciated. I attempted writing a loop in many ways, but the output would always turn out wrong, unlike how it works in this code. Thanks in advance.

```
std::string findConfPass(std::string link) {
  if (link.length() == 64) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(32, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  }
  if (link.length() == 65) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(33, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  }
  if (link.length() == 66) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(34, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  }
  if (link.length() == 67) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(35, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  }
  if (link.length() == 68) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(36, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  }
  if (link.length() == 69) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(37, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  }
  if (link.length() == 70) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(38, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  }
  if (link.length() == 71) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(39, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  }
  if (link.length() == 72) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(40, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  }
  if (link.length() == 73) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(41, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  }
  if (link.length() == 74) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(42, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  }
  if (link.length() == 75) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(43, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  } else {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(43, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
  }
}
```

What is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Off topic: don't pass string by value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `size_t len` your cases are

```
if (link.length() == len) {
    std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(len-32, 33);
    return foundConfPass;
}
```

Now you can see that all cases for `64 <= len <= 75` are identical when written like above. Only the else is different. Hence the whole function could be written as:

```
std::string findConfPass(std::string link) {
    auto len = link.length();
    if (64 <= len && len <= 75) {
         std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(len-32, 33);
         return foundConfPass;
    } else {
         std::string foundConfPass = link.substr(43, 33);
         return foundConfPass;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to do the same with a loop. I mean I could make up something that uses a loop, but it would be less simple than the above.

Note that unconditionally calling `link.substr(43, 33);` is problematic. You should check that the indices are valid. I merely showed you a way to write code that does exactly the same as yours.

Comment: If `link.length()` < 33, you have some problems in your `else` clause.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews aim was to provide something with exact output as the original, including issues. Will add a note

Comment: Both question and answer yield code that is difficult to maintain. In this case I would reconsider the method. You're not parsing a link, you trust length. Apparently the first part of this link can vary in size.  Does the second part have an introducer ? Then you could e.g. check for \question\ or ?q= in your string. Use strstr() to find the first occurence. When the second part has no introducer, but the first part does have a structure with a determined end.. parse the / terms properly.. it make your code easier to maintain and test, when anything would change in your "link" strings.

Comment: @Goodies note that the question at hand is "how to write this code with a loop?" and thats what I tried to answer (well.. without the "with a loop" part ;). "how to parse a link?" can be considered a different question, while parsing the link might be just an example here. its not all there is to say about the code, but one thing at a time

Comment: @Goodies consider to direct your suggestions to OP, they might miss them here

Comment: You are right, I only put my remark to suggest looking at the problem and the question from another angle. In fact, you did that as well, by *eliminating* the need for a loop alltogether. Don't get me wrong I like your answer which is an accurate intepretation of the question code at hand without need for a loop.. but in everyday life I would choose a different approach.